# Show resized image with cv2

Tags: python-3.x, image, windows-10, show, opencv, python

Windows 10

I reduced the code to the very core and the problem still exists.

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('imm.jpg')
cv2.imshow('image',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

In this way it works as it should: it shows an image with its resolution (4k). But if I resize it in this way:

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('imm.jpg')
res = cv2.resize(img, (160,90))
cv2.imshow('image',res)
cv2.waitKey()
```

it creates in the toolbar a new window, whose name's *image*, as it should but I cannot focus it and see the result. 
What's the problem?

Comment: For me, your code is working fine.

Comment: Solved simply by changing `'image'` to another random word I don't know why it worked.